# Callbacks in javascript and understanding to chain them

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I have a function which i am chaining into my callbacks in my node.js apis. While writing this for first time we had no scenario that it would be called individually too or as first method of chaining callbacks. So we wrote it like below

```
      processResults: (data, res, cb) => (error, response, body) => { // dostuff 
      // with response and process it
}
```

Now when the scenario to call processResults as the first method of callback chain arrived we did it like below

```
    app.post('/results, (req,res)=> {
    // call process results
        ctl.processResults(req.body,res,terminalCb)***()*** ;  
// () these seem to be wierd

    })
```

And to my surprise it works and now i am really confused how does this magic happens and somewhere i feel it is not the correct program writing technique. I really need help on this. Please if someone could explain or suggest a right way to code this or if this is the right way then why?
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You're just calling the inner function with no arguments: (error, response, body) will all be undefined, but it's permissible to do that just as it's permissible to call `arr.forEach(elm =>` with only one argument instead of three.

But if, as you said, the inner function does stuff with `response`, it won't work the way you typed your code because `response` will be undefined. `res` will be defined though, since you did pass that as a parameter to the outer function.

It would be nice if you could provide access to the default function directly, rather than only having a function that returns a function, like this:

```
const ctl = {
  processResults: (data, res, cb) => (error, response, body) => { // dostuff 
    // with response and process it
  }
}
ctl.processOne = function(data, res, cb) {
  return ctl1.processResults.call(this, ...arguments)();
}
```

You still have the ugly `()` but it's abstracted behind the object you're interfacing with.

Comment: i have a check that knows if response is not present then it needs to fetch it. Can i somehow re-write this to make it more readable? Any suggests?

Comment: Edited, see `ctl.processOne`